# WordPress: query pages except remove one page

Tags: loop, pages

I'm currently running this query to get pages (not posts) from the site section:

```
query_posts("post_type=page&post_parent=6");
```

I'd like to remove one page, 271, from this query. Based on [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518589/wordpress-removing-posts-in-the-loop-using-filters) I tried:

```
query_posts("p=-271&post_type=page&post_parent=6");
```

Unfortunately this had the opposite of the intended result, showing only page 271 and not the other pages in the loop. Placing the *p=-271* at the end of the query had the same unsuccessful result.

How can I reverse this to show all the other pages except page 271?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You must use exclude the page using `post__not_in` paremeter. Rewrite your query using the array parameters

```
query_posts(array(
'post__not_in'=>array('271'),
'post_parent'=>6,
'post_type'=>'page'
)
 );
```

See this [page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately when I try that code it throws an error (saying it needs an array). When I try this *query_posts(array("post__not_in=271&post_type=page&post_parent=6"));* it displays posts instead of pages. Anything else I can try?

Comment: See my edit: the query above retrieve all the childs of the page with ID 6 , excluding the page that has ID 271